# Missing error in loop (OpenMP with C)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

```
int count1(testcase *testcases, int n) {
    int i;
    int count = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (test(testcases[i]) == true) {
        ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

A bit of an unusual problem, namely that there seems to be no problem.
Teaching myself OpenMP for C, this is from a PDF on the topic I was reading.

The author hints that there is some problem with the code. Given n testcases, we have some function test that does something with the case and gives back a Boolean indicating wether the test was a success or not. This code snippet is supposed to count the number of tests. The author says, it does this *incorrectly* - I just don't get why. Been trying to wrap my mind around it for quite some time now and it's probably very simple.

I've been trying to code an example version of this with an array of 0s and 1s and substituting the

```
test(testcases[i]) == true
```

by an expression checking if it is a 1 and counting that. However, it counted my 1s correctly. Where is the mistake?

Comment: The correct way to do this is `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count)`. Try this and see if you can get it to make a difference. You could start with removing the conditional test and just incrementing `count`. It should equal `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the deal, this code could execute just fine but the problem is count variable, it is declared outside parallel region (aka for loop) and then incremented inside parallel region. So count increases run parallel and that creates a problem becouse what if 2 or more threads try to increment count at the same time, because belive me it will happen. Then wierd things will start to happen.

Variables are stored in memory right, so in order to increase value of variable we need to read it from memory (its current value), in CPU increase it and write it back. Now we run this sequence in parallel, so as an example this will happen sometimes (remember threads run in parallel):

1. Count in memory = 2
2. Thread 1 reads count (2)
3. Thread 2 reads count (2)
4. Thread 1 increases and writes back to count variable in memory (3)
5. Same thing does thread 2  (writes back 3)

So now in memory we have value of 3 in count variable, but since two threads were executed it should be 4. That is why this code will not work always. And this is just one of the things that could happen. That is why we know critical sections, semaphores, mutexes,... Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of that, but it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Most important, you should read up on reduction clause.  As OpenMP is not worth much without efficiency, you should also consider that such a simple case might be implemented more efficiently by single thread simd reduction than by non-simd parallel reduction, but you have possibilities for combining them.  Then there are language features (possibly not in plain C) to implement this which should be considered ahead of OpenMP.